# project euler 23 in java - close to solution

Tags: java, math

I've been working on this problem for a while and I was confident that my method would work. I got my current answer 4190404 with two different methods of finding the sum. In number 21 (amicable numbers) I used the same algorithm to sum of the divisors of a number making me confident it works properly. I've looked at blogs for guidance but I'm not getting anywhere. If someone can point me in the right direction i would be extremely grateful.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class problem23 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int upperLimit = 28123;
    long sum = 0;
```

List to hold all the abundant numbers under my upper limit

```
    ArrayList<Long> abunNums =  new ArrayList<Long>();
    abunNums.add((long) 0);

    for (long i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++)
        if (isAbundant(i)) 
            abunNums.add(i);
```

boolean array. true of the index is a sum of two abundant numbers and false if not

```
    boolean[] isSumOfAbun = new boolean[upperLimit+1];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < abunNums.size(); i++) {
        j = i;
        while (abunNums.get(i) + abunNums.get(j) <= upperLimit) {
            isSumOfAbun[(int) (abunNums.get(i) + abunNums.get(j))] = true;
            j++;
        }
    }
```

//loop through the boolean array and and the index to the sum if the number //cannot be described as a sum of two abundant numbers

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= upperLimit; i++) 
        if (!isSumOfAbun[i]) {
            sum += i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    System.out.println(sum);


}
```

method to test if a number is abundant

```
public static boolean isAbundant(long n) {

    long val = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i*i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0) {
            if (i == n/i)
                val += i;
            else
                val += i + (n/i);
        }

    if (val > n)
        return true;

    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what is wrong, but I have a feeling the isAbundant was wrong. Try using this version.

```
public static boolean isAbundant(long n) {
    long val = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            val += i;
        return val == n;
}
```

Comment: I also had a feeling isAbundant was wrong. Your revised method didn't help me get the correct solution though. After I find my list of abundant numbers and I scan through it nothing sticks out to me as being a major issue.

Comment: when reviewing other peoples answers I noticed many people were using algorithms involving prime numbers when identifying abundant numbers.